# Codeigniter define basepath or exit

Tags: security, codeigniter, controller

I noticed this small bit of code above a controller on a demo codeigniter project and wondered what it did and whether I should be using it.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Also if I should use it where should it be used? controllers? models? both? etc..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

in order to activate the codeigniter framework the site must accessed with www.blahblah.com/index.php/params . By going through index.php first the framework is activated and various classes and whatnot are ran through PHP. The framework then looks at the parameters of the url and activates a specific controller. This line of code makes sure that the framework has been properly "booted up" and the user merely isn't trying to run the single php file on the web server. Because that php file assumes that classes within the framework have already been declared, running a controller file on its own would fail miserably and has the potential for a security breach. No direct access allowed.

Comment: +1 pretty much spot on. Should also be noted it makes unit testing a pain.

Comment: oh right okay, would this bit of code also belong at the top of models or just controllers? Thanks

Comment: If you're going the CI way, it belongs in just about every script within CI's install. Note @AlienWebGuy's comment regarding testing, though...

Comment: Great answer, I never really understood this myself, but now I do.

Comment: So, does this prevent the controllers to be rerun/redeclared? In terms of security, if we're using Apache and have an [.htaccess with only a "deny from all" line](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html#Redirect_IP_alternate_page) in the _application_ folder, it prevents access to all of the controllers... Isn't this more practical than having these lines in all the controllers/models?

Comment: @Armfoot actually we have direct access to the controller and we need it and preventing the access by .htaccess is not a solution.Just sure "No direct script access allowed"  and in the background of running the controller we need to sure have a framework core.

Comment: Directly accessing a PHP file that just defines a class will not actually run any code. The config files present more of a risk. However, if the user is able to inject some other file (not index.php) that can import a class, then they can also define a BASEPATH constant and bypass this check. I don't think it really provides much, if anything, the way of real security.